# Why derivative of $\sec^ {-1}x$ is $\frac1{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ not $\frac1{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

When I try to calculate derivative of $y=\sec^{-1}x$  I get this:

$$\sec y=x\Rightarrow y '\times\sec y\tan y=1\Rightarrow\quad y '=\frac1{\sec y\tan y}=\frac{1}{\sec y. \sqrt{\sec^2y-1}}$$Hence I get $(\sec^{-1}x)'=\frac1{x\sqrt {x^2-1}}$ .

But in the book I'm reading, for $u=\sec^{-1}x$ it says $du=\frac{dx}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$. I don't know why we should use absolute value bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can check that $\sec^{-1}$ is an increasing function wherever it's defined, so its derivative definitely should be positive everywhere it's defined.

Implicitly in the last step of your top equation, you used $\tan y = \sqrt{(\tan y)^2}$, but this is not correct: we actually have $|\tan y| = \sqrt{(\tan y)^2}$. (This isn't the exact algebraic step that gives the $|x|$ in the formula, but it's the root issue.) When $\sec y\le-1$ (on the chosen domain $[0,\pi]$ for $\sec^{-1}$), we have $\tan y<0$, and so the absolute value matters.

See also [this page](https://secure.math.ubc.ca/%7ECLP/CLP1/clp_1_dc/sec_inv_trig.html) for a graph of $\sec^{-1} x$, and [Example 2.12.7 on this page](https://secure.math.ubc.ca/%7ECLP/CLP1/clp_1_dc/subsection-36.html) for a different derivation of the closely related derivative of $\csc^{-1} x$.